# Add Custom module PHTML in My order View page?

Tags: magento2

I add phtml in frontend sales order view page.
frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View">
        <plugin name="sales-order-view-seller" type="Companyname\Modulename\Plugin\Block\Order\View" />
  </type>
</config>
```

View.php

```
<?php

namespace Companyname\Modulename\Plugin\Block\Order;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View $originalBlock) {

        $originalBlock->setTemplate('Companyname_Modulename::seller_review_view.phtml');
    }
}
```

Code is working but phtml content showing two times.
Any Thing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom phtml in order view page like this

**[Namespace]\[Modulename]\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="[Namespace]\[Modulename]\Block\Comment" template="[Namespace]_[Modulename]::view.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**[Namespace]\[Modulename]\Block\Comment.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[Modulename]\Block;
   class Comment extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = []
     ) {
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   ----Your Block Method----
}
```

**[Namespace]\[Modulename]\view\frontend\templates\view.phtml**

```
<?php echo "Hii"?>
```

If you don't want to make your custom block than in xml write block class `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`